# acts_as_tree default foreign key column

Tags: ruby

Rubydoc [says](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/acts_as_tree/2.1.0),

> By default, ActsAsTree expects a foreign key column called parent_id

My question is, how can we change the default foreign key column to some custom column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it on initialization

```
class Foo   
  acts_as_tree foreign_key: :whatever
  ...
end
```

See documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/acts_as_tree/2.1.0/ActsAsTree/ClassMethods#acts_as_tree-instance_method